# Azure Flask web app + Azure SQL + Github | 500 server error every day

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I've created Flask web app which is connected to an Azure SQL db. The app works just fine locally and I've pushed it successfully using two methods (i) Github and (ii) External Repository. When it is just pushed, everything works just fine, but for some reason, it will later on within the day (or the next day) crash and provide an 500 internal server error. When I push it again, it works just fine... and so on and so forth.

I've looked at a majority of post related to this issue but I could not find a solution so far. The thing is I don't really know where to look to find a solution. The Azure diagnosies isn't helpful in this case and just tells me :

[image: azure diganosis]

I thought it might be the connections string with the db, but it works just fine for a day before the app crashed.
Then I though it might be the service plan, but I tried several (test & prod) and the problem remains.
I suspect it might be the app server itself, but I don't know where to look to confirm.

Any ideas on how to resolve such an issue ?

Flask app = Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work. I hope it will last and that it'll help someone in the same situation.

**I. Kudu :**

1. Go to the Kudo console : `myAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/`,
2. Go to Bash menu (I'm Linux based),
3. `cd LogFiles`,
4. `cat 2021_10_08_xxx_docker.log`,
5. I found this :

[image: Kudu LogFiles]

**II. Azure CLI :**

1. After a bit of research, I found this command to modify the WEBSITES_PORT :

   `az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <ressource-group> --name <appname> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=8000`.